# Embeddables and moving from wordpress.com to self host

Tags: wordpress, embed

I transfered my wordpress blog from .com to a self host but it is full with embeds from youtube and flickr, written like thus:

> [youtube=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=someurl]

and so how do I go about converting those wordpress.com embeds to normal embeds?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) is a good plugin to be able to search and replace with Grep through all posts and pages. With that, you can change your shortcodes to the default [Embeds « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) that self-hosted Wordpress uses, which in its simplest form is just the URL.

Or use [WordPress › Viper's Video Quicktags « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vipers-video-quicktags/) and search/replace to convert to that form of shortcode.

And https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for Wordpress questions.

Answer (score 0):

For youTube, you should go back to the video on YouTube.com and grab the embed code.

What other objects do you need to embed?

Answer (score 0):

Use the JetPack plug-in, it provides most of the embedded shortcodes that you normally use in WordPress.com